# Second image is cropping the backplate!

Tags: materials, node-editor, transparency, masking

Hello my fellow blenders.

I was playing around with adding decals with the shader editor/nodes but I stumbled upon a problem where the mask of the 2. image is also masking everything outside the image. How can I change that?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tagged texture is alpha and black if outside the texture, using clipping in the image texture node.

You can use this alpha channel this way so that the fac value stays 0 when outside of the texture:

[image]

[image]